# How to fix ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound when liking comment?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, comments

When a user tries to like a comment he is confronted with this error:

```
ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound (Couldn't find Comment with 'id'=3 [WHERE "comments"."user_id" = ?]):
  app/controllers/comments_controller.rb:58:in `set_comment'
```

I keep tinkering with one of the lines in the controller, but I'm not sure if that's the answer.

**comments_controller**

```
class CommentsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_commentable, only: [:index, :new, :create]
  before_action :set_comment, only: [:edit, :update, :destroy, :like]
  before_action :correct_user, only: [:edit, :update, :destroy]

  def index
    @comments = @commentable.comments
  end

  def new
    @comment = @commentable.comments.new
  end

  def create
    @comment = @commentable.comments.new(comment_params)
    if @comment.save
      redirect_to @commentable, notice: "Comment created."
    else
      render :new
    end
  end

  def edit
  end

  def update
    if @comment.update_attributes(comment_params)
      redirect_to :back, notice: "Comment was updated."
    else
      render :edit
    end
  end

  def destroy
    @comment.destroy
    redirect_to @comment.commentable, notice: "Comment destroyed."
  end

  def like
    @comment = Comment.find(params[:id]) # I've been tinkering with this line.
    @comment_like = current_user.comment_likes.build(comment: @comment)
    if @comment_like.save
      @comment.increment!(:likes)
      flash[:success] = 'Thanks for liking!'
    else
      flash[:error] = 'Too many likes'
    end  
    redirect_to(:back)
  end

  private

  def set_commentable
    @commentable = find_commentable
  end

  def set_comment
    @comment = current_user.comments.find(params[:id])
  end

  def correct_user
    @comment = current_user.comments.find_by(id: params[:id])
    redirect_to root_url, notice: "Not authorized to edit this comment" if @comment.nil?
  end

  def find_commentable
    if params[:goal_id]
      Goal.find(params[:goal_id])
    elsif params[:habit_id]
      Habit.find(params[:habit_id])
    elsif params[:valuation_id]
      Valuation.find(params[:valuation_id])
    elsif params[:stat_id]
      Stat.find(params[:stat_id])
    end
  end

  def comment_params
    params[:comment][:user_id] = current_user.id
    params.require(:comment).permit(:content, :commentable, :user_id, :like)
  end
end
```

**comment_like.rb**

```
class CommentLike < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :comment
  belongs_to :habit
  belongs_to :stat
  belongs_to :valuation
  belongs_to :goal
  validates :user, uniqueness: { scope: :comment }
  belongs_to :liker, class_name: 'User', foreign_key: :user_id
  belongs_to :liked_comment, class_name: 'Comment', foreign_key: :comment_id
end
```

**comment.rb**

```
class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base
    after_save :create_notification
  has_many :notifications
  has_many :comment_likes   
  has_many :likers, through: :comment_likes, class_name: 'User', source: :liker
  belongs_to :habit
  belongs_to :stat
  belongs_to :valuation
  belongs_to :goal
    belongs_to :user
  validates :user, presence: true

private

  def create_notification
    author = 
      if goal
        goal.user
      #elsif comment_like
      # comment_like.user
      elsif habit
       habit.user
      elsif stat
        stat.user
      elsif valuation
        valuation.user
      end
    notifications.create(
      comment:      self,
      likes:        likes,
      habit:        habit,
      stat:         stat,
      goal:         goal,
      valuation:    valuation,
      user:         author,      
      read:         false
    )
  end
end
```

**schema**

```
  create_table "comment_likes", force: true do |t|
    t.integer  "user_id"
    t.integer  "comment_id"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
  end

  create_table "comments", force: true do |t|
    t.text     "content"
    t.integer  "goal_id"
    t.integer  "habit_id"
    t.integer  "valuation_id"
    t.integer  "stat_id"
    t.integer  "commentable_id"
    t.string   "commentable_type"
    t.integer  "user_id"
    t.datetime "created_at",       null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",       null: false
    t.integer  "likes"
  end

  add_index "comments", ["commentable_id", "commentable_type"], name: "index_comments_on_commentable_id_and_commentable_type"
  add_index "comments", ["commentable_type", "commentable_id"], name: "index_comments_on_commentable_type_and_commentable_id"
  add_index "comments", ["user_id"], name: "index_comments_on_user_id"
```

Everything else works, like the ability to comment and like a user's own comment, but not when a user tries to like someone else's comment.

Comment: Does this happen with this comment only or with all comments?

Comment: It always happens when a user tries to like another user's comment @AhmadAl-kheat. Love the profile pic :-]

Comment: You have a filter to set the comment before like, and then you are finding the comment again inside the like method, I don't know why you are doing this. Thanks ;)

Comment: I guess you don't need to set_comment before like

Comment: Okay I had put that line in thinking that was the problem. I'll take it out, but the error still remains @AhmadAl-kheat :/

Comment: Are you sure the error is exactly the same when you change the before filter?

Comment: No you are right I misunderstood you :/ I'm debating the two answers now @AhmadAl-kheat

Comment: Go with your heart :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error is caused by

```
before_action :set_comment, only: [:edit, :update, :destroy, :like]
```

Remove `:like` will solve the issue.

Other lines of code of your original post are fine.

Because the `Comment` which `current_user` likes DOES NOT BELONG TO `current_user`, `current_user.comments.find(params[:id])` will raise `ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound`.

Answer (score 1):

As per the documentation [here](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/FinderMethods.html#method-i-find), an `ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound` exception will be thrown if the record is not found.

The error message states `app/controllers/comments_controller.rb:58:in 'set_comment'`. `set_comment` seems to be getting called because you tell your controller to call it as a `before_action`

`before_action :set_comment, only: [:edit, :update, :destroy, :like]`

`set_comment` does the following

`@comment = current_user.comments.find(params[:id])`

It's only looking within the scope of the `current_user`'s comments, which explains why a user can like his own comments but not anyone else's. You need to change it to

`@comment = Comment.find(params[:id])`

Now it'll look for all comments with that id. Also, this means you can remove the first line of the `like` action since it does the same thing as `set_comment` which is redundant (you're querying your db twice).

Comment: This doesn't seem to work Adib because now whenever I try to like a comment I get the error, "Two many likes" for some reason. So I think Aetherus's answer might be the best one unless I'm doing something wrong here in which case your answer would be better since its one less line of code :]

Comment: You shouldn't dismiss error messages, swap SO answers and not understand what your code is doing. The reason you're getting that is because `@comment_like.save` failed to save, which is probably because `@comment_like.valid?` is false (it's an invalid record). Just before you save the comment_like, print `@comment_like.errors` to the console to get a list of errors.

Comment: @Adib, if he does what you suggest, other methods will break because he structured his code in a way that depends on finding the comment of the current_user to allow him to edit/update/destroy it. So I don't recommend this way in this case. But you are right, it should be done like that in an ideal world.

Comment: Thanks @Adib I understand my code, not well enough though I fully admit. Still a lot to learn, but Ahmad is right. I was worried about going down a rabbit hole so I'll go with the safe answer for now. Thanks for offering me additional insight though :]

Comment: @AhmadAl-kheat That's what the `before_action :correct_user, only: [:edit, :update, :destroy]` is for. If anything, that filter should be the very first and `set_comment` shouldn't exist, leaving line 1 of `like` alone.